# Increase the number each time the script is run from 0 to 999 and start over

Tags: bash

I have a scripts that needs to change the number each time is run. There can be max 3 digits from 0 to 999, it needs to repeat after it reaches 999.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Ncat is a part of the nmap, install nmap to use ncat

#Define variables
i=poland.aprs2.net
port=14580
lat=3439.94N
lon=02517.67E_ #_ is a symbol for WX station
user=APRS
password=99999

#Generate authentication data
aprsauth="user $user pass $password filter m/50"

#Generate Weather data
xastir="$user>APX206,TCPIP*:!$lat/$lon".../...g...t...h41X210""

#Telemetry data
t1="$user>APX206,TCPIP*:T#672,060,000,000,000,000,00000000"

#Send data to the APRS server
printf "%s\n" "$aprsauth" "$xastir" "$t1"| ncat --send-only $i $port

#Output control
printf "%s\n" "$aprsauth" "$xastir" "$t1"
```

Code that needs to be changed is T#**672**
from:

```
t1="$user>APX206,TCPIP*:T#672,060,000,000,000,000,00000000"
```

T#xxx is a sequence number in APRS protocol, and it only supports 3 digits. Each telemetry report needs a different sequence number.

Comment: The `echo` is superfluous: `t1="$user>APX206,TCPIP*:T#672,060,000,000,000,000,00000000"`

Comment: Maybe I can use shuf -i 0-999 -n 1 but that will randomize and there is a lottery chance I get the same number on the second run.

Answer (score 6):

You need to maintain some sort of external state: write the last number used to a file, and read from that file on startup so you can incremented t it.

```
read num < /var/run/myscript/last_value
num=$((num + 1))
if (( num == 1000 )); then
    num=0
fi
echo "$num" > /var/run/myscript/last_value

...

printf -v t1 "%s>APX206,TCPIP*:T#%03d,060,000,000,000,000,00000000" "$user" "$num"
```

Comment: I get num not found error for the line in your script where num=0 but other than that it works, it changes the number.

Comment: I got it, I had the wrong shell defined, /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash

Comment: I can adjust the answer to work with `/bin/sh` if you like. None of the `bash`-specific features I used are necessary.

Comment: More concisely, assuming `bash` not `sh`, `num=$(( (num+1) % 1000 ))`. Also, I'd try to minimise the time between the read and the write: `num=$(( ( $(< "$counter_file") + 1) % 1000 )); echo "$num" > "$counter_file"`

Comment: Good point about updating the file as soon as possible. More work would need to be done if you wanted to accommodate concurrent updates to the state file, but there's no compelling reason to delay updating the file.

Comment: @chepner I've got it all working smoothly, but how would you write a script to pad zeros infront? 001, 002, 010, 011, so always 3 digits.

Comment: @newbie123 You don't need to. The `printf` statement in my example takes care of the padding at the point of use (`%03d`).